# How to break table elements after a certain amount?

Tags: php, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a table from database values. I got 37 items to display and i want them to break after 10 elements.

I tryed to use flexbox but it seems im just to stupid. :/

```
<style>
.container {
height:100%;
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.item{
flex-grow: 1;
overflow: auto;
}
</style>


<div class="container">
<form>
foreach($elements as $elem){
echo "<td class="item"><input type="checkbox"/>
}
</form>
</div>
```

After 10 elements it needs to break. but it dosen't and i dont know how to fix it ! Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "break"?

Comment: ..and why are you applying flexbox to `table` elements?

Comment: I have to display 10 <th> after which follow 10 <td>. Now i need a <tr> yet, i dont know how to solve this the best way..

Comment: don't know if i understand you correctly... but you could declare a simple counter variable before the loop, count it upwards inside it and and then return what you need. eg. when variable < 10 return th, variable%10 == 0 return tr or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
echo '<tr>'
$count = 0;
foreach($elements as $elem){
    if ($count >= 9){
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        $count = 0;
    }
    echo 'what you want (your $elem for example)'
    $count++;
}
echo '</tr>'
```

solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

in your example error. You use php code without

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <?php foreach($elements as $number => $elem):
           if ($number > 10) {
               break;
           }            

           echo "<td class="item"><input type="checkbox"/>
        } ?>
   </form>
</div>
```